# Reverse Proxy with Restlet

Tags: android, server, reverse-proxy, restlet

I want to set a Reslet reverse proxy server running on Android, and I want to send whole traffic from another device to server and intercept all requests.

I found nothing about it, How can I do this?

If I couldn't do it with Restlet framework, what framework permits me do it in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do reverse proxy with Restlet, this code shows an example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        String target = "http://otherservice.​com/users.xml";
        Redirector redirector = new Redirector(getContext(), target, Redirector.MODE_SERV​ER_OUTBOUND);
        router.setDefaultMat​chingMode(Router.MOD​E_FIRST_MATCH);

        getConnectorService(​).getClientProtocols​().add(Protocol.HTTP​);

        router.attachDefault​(redirector);

        return router;
    }
}
```

From [reverse proxy on AppEngine (restlet 2.1) : 404 - client protocol missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874649/reverse-proxy-on-appengine-restlet-2-1-404-client-protocol-missing)